# make excel from database and send it to mail in php

Tags: php, excel, email, header

i have created a excel file and i want to send it in mail . can anyone tell how can i do it .
mail is going but excel file is not going .I am using mysql server in php .
this is my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
 include ('../db_connect.php');

$user = $_SESSION['album_id'];
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=selected_image.xls");

 echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Imgae Name";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Image Comment";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$select_all = "select * from select_album where user_inf_id = '".$user."' and status = '1'";
$query_All = mysql_query($select_all) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_All))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row_all['user_image'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row_all['user_comment'];
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

                $to         =   '2606ankit@gmail.com';  //put email address on which mail send
               $subject     =   "TEST SUBJECT";                 //Put subject of mail here
               $from        =   "webmaster@example.com";        //put email address from 
               //email body start
               $body        =   "Selected image mail";

               // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
                $headers .=  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
                $headers .=  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=selected_image.xls");
                // More headers
                $headers .= 'From: '.$from. "\r\n";

                //if you need to send cc mail then uncomment below line and change email address
                //$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

                mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);


?>
```

i have created a excel file and i want to send it in mail . can anyone tell how can i do it .
mail is going but excel file is not going .I am using mysql server in php .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send attachments, I highly recommend that you use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). It definitely is the easier option. Attaching something is really as easy as:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

To implement it, all you need to do is

1. download it [here](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer);
2. move the entire "PHPMailer-master" folder to somewhere in your project, and;
3. include it in the php file you want it in with this: require 'Path/To/This/File/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

I use it for sending any email, but it's especially useful when you want to send attachments. It really simplifies things.

**EDIT**

There are numerous examples in the download, but here is a more complete example for sending from a Gmail account:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'gmailaccountusername@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'YOUR NAME';
$mail->addAddress('recipient@gmail.com', 'RECIPIENT NAME');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyemail@gmail.com', 'REPLY NAME');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/File/Path/To/Attachment.png');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

// Send the email

$mail->Subject = 'EMAIL SUBJECT';
$mail->Body    = 'BODY OF EMAIL WHICH CAN INCLUDE HTML';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: please tell me another option to do it simple

Comment: There are numerous examples in the download that you can follow. I also added an edit above detailing a more complete implementation. You will have to do some work, however, since I don't know anything about your email provider (SMTP host, port, etc.).